# Spring Boot project build failed - cannot find package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have got a massive problem with my Spring Boot project. For some reason, when starting my application, I get a project build failure error as per screenshot.

It is a huge surprise as I have been developing this app for a while now and obviously launching it number of times without any problems. Today, I wanted to start it again and got that error and yesterday everything worked fine!!! Moreover, I didn't make any modifications to the code or settings.
It cannot find some packages, even though they do exist.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.maciejdluzen</groupId>
    <artifactId>hotelreservation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hotelreservation</name>
    <description>Hotel reservation system in Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1** - some additional info:

I know that I have got some mess with java versions I've been using as `mvn clean install` throws the following error (but when I was launching the app using Intellij green arrow button, it was all fine):

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project hotelreservation: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release
: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

So in my Maven dependencies I have got Java 11  `<java.version>11</java.version>`

`java -version` and `javac -version` show respectively `1.8` and `9` version.

In the Intellij IDE settings Project SDK is set to Java `14.0.2` and only the following SDKs are available:
[image]

**java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
```

**javac - version**

```
javac 9.0.1
```

**mvn -v**

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_261, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre
```

Comment: Intellij IDEA, right? Try "invalidate caches/restart"

Comment: @lealceldeiro - unfortunately, that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either install java 11 SDK and add it to Intellij, or change the java verion in the pom.xml to one of the installed version, like:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Wondering why this didn't cause any trouble for weeks until today.

Comment: Maybe there was an automatic update? Or a compability mode was set and somehow it was turned off...

Answer (score 0):

Try with fallowing annotation on main class with `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.my.pkg")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried rebuilding the Maven project?

Comment: Do you mean ``mvn clean install`` - it doesn't work at all (and actually never worked). I think I have some mess with java version settings - I have added an edit with some explaination.